# What causes frozen "shooting water" spikes from ice covered water in the winter?

Tags: meteorology, ice

I have seen things like this appear once or twice on cold winter mornings, a frozen spike of water from an ice-covered container or very small body of water (puddle).

I found the photo below at [Mel Bartels and BBAstroDesigns](https://www.bbastrodesigns.com/)
 and the caption reads:

> An ice spike in a bird bath following a cold snap December 2014

What could be happening here? How might the two structures form like this, both tilted against gravity?

**update:** Comments indicate that Wikipedia's article [Ice spike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_spike) gives an explanation based on the growth of a tube as the freezing process extends from top-down into the liquid, pushing remaining liquid out a hole and growing vertically from a central opening in the tube.

However, I can't see how this makes a spike with such a large angle with respect to vertical. It really looks to my untrained eye like this is a frozen jet, but that's not so likely as water is not so compressible.

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icicle and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_spike explained here unless I am missing something ?

Comment: @gansub there it is in all it's glory, bird-bath and all. It's an ice-spike, I'll update the question accordingly. The large angle with respect to vertical shown in the question and [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ice-Spike.jpg) are particularly hard to understand, and this isn't really addressed in the Wikipedia article. I'll try to drill down on some of the references shown there. Thanks!